# PHP sha256 hash different than Java Guava one

Tags: java, php, hash, sha256

I'm trying to validate sha256 hashes generated via Java Guava Hashing class using PHP, but can't seem to do it. I can't touch Java files, so fix has to be done on PHP side. Both PHP and Java use UTF-8 encoding. What am I missing?

Java:

```java
package org.test.hash;

import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String salt = "0123456789012345";
        String password = "password";

        System.out.println(
            Hashing.sha256().hashUnencodedChars(salt + "|" + password).toString()
        );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
818112d34d341ace8b9325fce61e676a125f733e25c28c9ed172c1f7d2c3aa6c
```

PHP:

```php
$salt = "0123456789012345";
$password = "password";
print_r(hash("sha256", $salt . "|" . $password));
```

Output:

```
1f0a70940ae365e930c51e3de4c0a82f853f7663fc17acd36406982666685703
```

Comment: A quick look at the javadoc suggests that you should use [`hashString`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashFunction.html#hashString(java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.charset.Charset)) instead of [`hashUnencodedChars`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashFunction.html#hashUnencodedChars(java.lang.CharSequence)) (which basically encodes the low byte and high byte of a Java `char`, that is as if UTF-16 is used to convert the string to bytes.

Comment: Can't touch the java part, but I'll try to convert my string to UTF-16 in PHP code once I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to suggestions from comments. It seems that bad implementation on Java end (using `hashUnencodedChars` instead of `hashString`) is causing conversion from source encoding (UTF-8 in my case) to UTF-16LE. Here's a way to fix that on PHP side:

```php
$salt = "0123456789012345";
$password = "password";
$salted = mb_convert_encoding($salt . "|" . $password, "UTF-16LE", "UTF-8")
print_r(hash("sha256", $salted));
```

Output:

```
818112d34d341ace8b9325fce61e676a125f733e25c28c9ed172c1f7d2c3aa6c
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a string encoding difference, check the following with Python:

```py
>>> from hashlib import sha256
>>> string = "0123456789012345|password"

>>> sha256(string.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
'1f0a70940ae365e930c51e3de4c0a82f853f7663fc17acd36406982666685703'

>>> sha256(string.encode("utf-16-le")).hexdigest()
'818112d34d341ace8b9325fce61e676a125f733e25c28c9ed172c1f7d2c3aa6c'

>>> string.encode("utf-8").hex()
'303132333435363738393031323334357c70617373776f7264'

>>> string.encode("utf-16-le").hex()
'30003100320033003400350036003700380039003000310032003300340035007c00700061007300730077006f0072006400'
```

Comment: That's a good hint, thanks! I didn't think that Java converts string to utf-16-le before hashing. I'll try to reproduce that in PHP once I get home and update this post